# Merge two dataframe with groupby AND a list of names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hel lo I have 2 dataframes such as :

Dataframe1

```
GroupName weigth Name
Group1 34 Baby1
Group1 43 Baby2
Group1 34 Baby3
Group2 32 Baby4
Group2 32 Baby2
Group3 33 Baby9
```

Dataframe2

```
GroupName Size ListNames
Group1 89 ['Baby1','Baby2']
Group1 87 ['Baby3']
Group2 78 ['Baby4','Baby2']
Group3 80 ['Baby9']
```

and I would like to merge the two dataframes by `GroupName` and by `ListNames`
Here I should get for instance :

Dataframe3

```
GroupName weigth Name Size ListNames
Group1 34 Baby1 89 ['Baby1','Baby2']
Group1 43 Baby2 89 ['Baby1','Baby2']
Group1 34 Baby3 87 ['Baby3']
Group2 32 Baby4 78 ['Baby4','Baby2']
Group2 32 Baby2 78 ['Baby4','Baby2']
Group3 33 Baby9 80 ['Baby9']
```

I know we shoult use groupby 'GroupName' but I do not know how to deal with tha `ListNames` in pandas. Does someone have an idea? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create column `Name` with same values like `ListNames` and repeat rows by [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+), then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) together:

```
#if necessary convert strings to lists
import ast
#df2['ListNames'] = df2['ListNames'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = df1.merge(df2.assign(Name=df2['ListNames']).explode('Name'), on=['GroupName','Name'])
print (df)
  GroupName  weigth   Name  Size       ListNames
0    Group1      34  Baby1    89  [Baby1, Baby2]
1    Group1      43  Baby2    89  [Baby1, Baby2]
2    Group1      34  Baby3    87         [Baby3]
3    Group2      32  Baby4    78  [Baby4, Baby2]
4    Group2      32  Baby2    78  [Baby4, Baby2]
5    Group3      33  Baby9    80         [Baby9]
```